# Create multiple buttons from database in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium

What I am trying to do is create a set of buttons for each row found in my SQLite database. I am testing this on the iPad simulator. Using titanium SDK 2.1.4

Here is what I have:

```
var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var db = Ti.Database.install('../databasename.sqlite', 'table'); //Install SQLite Database
var rows = db.execute('SELECT DISTINCT row FROM table');



var brandView = Ti.UI.createView({   //Primary view for buttons
        title: 'Hello',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
});
currentWin.add(brandView);

for(var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {   //Pull DB Info
var buttonCount = new Array(rows.length);   //Create Button names
for(var i = 0; i < buttonCount.length; i++) {
    buttonCount[i] = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: rows[j].name,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    });
    brandView.add(buttonCount[i]);
}
}
```

It loads without any error, and loads the window, and the view I am calling but no buttons.  How can I create a group of buttons based on the retrieved database info?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your use of the buttonCount array or your two for loops. Will this work?

```
for(var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: rows[j].name,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        top: j * 105 // space the buttons at 105
    });
    brandView.add(btn);
}
```